# Проблема с заменой слеша в пути на Python

Tags: python

В функцию передается путь вида D:\folder\file.txt
Проблема в том, что функция os.path.dirname(src) корректно работает только с путями с двойным слешем \ или с одинарным обратным слешем.

Вроде бы нужно всего лишь замену сделать, однако у меня замена приводит к какой-то аброкадабре
src path = D:/ProjectБ4rchdata♀older1.ini

я не могу понять откуда берутся эти спец символы. Может функция os.path.dirname некорректно работает?

Вот сам код

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import os
import ntpath
import shutil

    dst_sav = "D:\\savorsk\\"
    #.replace("\\","/")

    def copyfilestofolder(src):
        src = src.replace("\\","/")
        print "src path = %s" %src
        dbfilepath = os.path.dirname(src)
        print dbfilepath

    copyfilestofolder("D:\Project\2014\archdata\folder1.ini")
```

Мне нужно лишь как-то получить в переменную dbfilepath путь до каталога в котором лежит файл, однако ничего не получается.

Подскажите решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Двойной слеш в строке это вовсе не 2 символа. Тоесть

```
>>> print '\\'
\
```

и вам не нужно заменять 2 слеша на 1.

А вам нужно передавать исходный путь файла как

```
"D:\\Project\\2014\\archdata\\folder1.ini"
```

Так как \P, \2, \a, \f - в строке будут интерпретироваться как спецсимволы

Comment: А как это сделать? .replace("два слеша", "четыре слеша") ?

*парсер глючит заменил словами

Comment: Заменять вообще ничего не нужно. Вы пишите 2 слеша, питон думает что это 1. Все.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то лучше всего использовать спецификатор **r** для строки, который обозначает - строка вводится в сыром формате(экранировать при этом ничего не надо). Одинаково хорошо подходит как для регулярных выражений, так и для путей:

```
 r"D:\Project\2014\archdata\folder1.ini"
```

спецификатор можно задавать в верхнем регистре

Плюсы такого решения в том, что не падает читабельность по сравнению с экранированием.